# setMuted() and setCurrentTime() on IPad using mediaelementjs 2.10.1

Tags: html, ipad, mediaelement.js

I created a video player using `mediaelementjs` for multi-platform compatibility. Everything works fine apart from IPad2. The methods `setMuted()` and `setCurrentTime()` are not working on iPad2.

Please let me know if you have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

As far for `setCurrentTime()` I had faced the same problem for iPad1 and iPad2.
I can't fully recall the solution I came up with but as far as I remember
I created the mediaelement dynamically and assigned it to a global variable `player`, or whatever you want.
When I needed to set the current time, I just did:

```
player.setCurrentTime(1.250);
```

If you post some code we might help you more.